# Find the value of area of $\triangle ADF$ by AG and AE

Tags: geometry

Consider a $\triangle ABC$ where $\angle A = 60^\circ$. Let $O$ be the inscribed circle of $\triangle ABC$, as shown in the figure. Let $D$, $E$, $F$ be the points at which circle $O$ is tangent to the sides $AB$, $BC$ and $CA$. And let $G$ be the point of intersection of the line segment $AE$ and the circle $O$. Set $x=AD$.

$$\frac{\text{area of } \triangle ADF}{|AG|\cdot|AE|}=\text{?}$$
[image: figure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $|AD|=|AF|=x$, and since we have that $\angle A=60^\circ$, $\mathrm{Area}(ADF) = \dfrac{1}{2}x^2\sin(60^\circ)=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4}x^2$.  Also, note that by the [power of a point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) $x^2=|AF|^2=|AG|\cdot|AE|$.

Hence 
$$\frac{\mathrm{Area}(ADF)}{|AG|\cdot|AE|}=\frac{\frac{\sqrt3}{4}x^2}{x^2}=\frac{\sqrt3}{4}$$